# 'Information nature' of transfer function?

Tags: transfer-function

**Doubt:** before I thought I had understood the transfer function, now, I realize that I did not understand what transfer function is it on a *structural* level , that is how it 'makes a circuit' or is manifested or implemented concretely because I see a [translation motion](https://www.quora.com/What-is-translational-motion) here where function is integrated when a [Shift Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) is provided or better, is induced by control system or still better, technically we have a a differential operator of an electric field (a complex field C)

> In mathematics, and in particular functional analysis, the shift operator also known as translation operator is an operator that takes a function x ↦ f(x) to its translation x ↦ f(x + a)
>
> Translational motion is movement of an object (in [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object) and [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inductive+limit) sense) without a change in its orientation relative to a fixed point.

---

> In mathematics, a fixed point (sometimes called an invariant point) of a function is an element of the function's domain that is mapped to itself by the function

I know that the amplifier amplifies in the sense of 'gain', but the gain depends, and I do not understand here, how the transfer function is defined (is just a calculation or it is reflected by a shift operator ? This is not very clear)

What I do not understand is if the transfer function, concretely, can be calculated by an operational amplifier in the physically operative sense of the term because to do this we need to have an linear functional because we need to have a current not a physical movement because we talk about of trasfer function, not about information extraction !

> Basically, current **doesn’t** flow because current is just *measurement*. It is developed by *flow* of electrons. Current is rate of flow of charge.

But this flow of charge how is determinated in relation of transfer function ?

A flow formalizes the *idea* of the motion of current because the direction of *current* flow is opposite to the direction of *electron* flow.

The related question is about the 'information nature' of transfer function: is this a signal action like a 'function' (and therefore I ask how it is done) or, if the function, here, is to be calculated in another meaning, that is, something that is extracted or indirectly calculated as a 'behavior' of the circuit, an impulsive response, etc. but.. in this case we should, mathematically speaking, talk about of *image function*

> an image is the subset of a function's codomain which is the output of the function from a subset of its domain

Definition of transfer function is instead

> It is often represented as a graph, called a transfer *curve* or characteristic curve. The transfer function provides *information* which specifies the behavior of the component in a system

What type of function is this curve ? Exponential, logarithmic.. ? Because if it provide information you need a function to do that, maybe a *constant* function ?

I find that is **method** of characteristics for solving partial differential equations, so this is the 'function' of transfer function ? But is not clear if I want to induce a transfer function (Current–voltage characteristic) I need a [Semiconductor curve tracer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_curve_tracer)

Comment: a few errors in your definitions but basically each block is Out/in with some units that relate e.g.f/V* V/RPM *load/RPM etc or H(s)*G(s) in s domain and if all linear they are all mutliplied in series. Curve tracer is Iout/In with Iout=y vs Vce=x with staircase step current Ib at any frequency like 100Hz x n steps with Hsync on first step base current and variable load R.

Comment: keep reading how things work.

Comment: Slow down, I think I just had a brain aneurysm. Couple ideas that could clarify things: 1) transfer functions should be understood in the context of *signals* and *systems*, which are applied mathematics concepts. Its mapping function is defined as a signal convolution on time domain. The domain is the input signal, the image is the output signal. "Translation motion" may be misguided.

Comment: 2) A certain level of thought abstraction is required. Transfer functions exist in maths independent of a real circuit implementation. To think about how current relates to a transfer function requires a circuit for context, because the inputs and outputs of the transfer function could very well be these currents, or any other signal in the circuit.

Comment: I got to the bottom of the question and couldn't remember if a question was actually made.

Comment: You are overthinking this way too much. I could barely read the whole thing. Maybe a smal break to clear your head would be better? (no sarcasm)

Comment: @VicenteCunha "*The domain is the input signal, the image is the output signal*" - and your next comment give me great clarification. When you say *these currents* you refer physical currents? I think that we should start from a math definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_(mathematics)) because a physical current is an [*action functional*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+functional), so when you say "*transfer function could be any other signal*" the idea is that *translation motion* is not a physical translation but an an affine transformation with no fixed points

Comment: because should be a *function translation* from **[translation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#translation)** point of view because to get an *information* we need to change function 'position' but in generalized terms :: *the position operator is the operator that corresponds to the position observable of a particle. The eigenvalue of the operator is the position vector of the particle*. I suspect that transfer function change function position so my idea that we have a Shift operator

Comment: This is no simply because if we talk about physical particles to understand relationship with a 'concrete transfer function' *circuit application* we need to change standard representation into a maybe more abstract [Gamma Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) because could help us because where and *what* really transfer function, transfers. Another thing:transfer function is on complex field C, but if we start from upper half-space H following [this](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-functions-that-are-holomorphic-on-the-upper-half-plane-and-not-the-entire-complex-plane)?

Comment: @user332153 Apologies for the mistake, you must understand that "current" for an electrical engineer is the same as "electric current". Still, you are employing a far greater deal of theory and formalism than necessary to grasp "transfer functions". All that you need is linear systems theory. If you wish for structural understanding, study state-space representation of systems. Once you understand how inputs can influence a system's states, and how states can influence a system's output, the input-to-output nature of transfer function comes naturally.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I follow your tip, I see now Kronecker vector-matrix structures for State-space representation, this is for me, *thanks again* ! If you want you can put your last comment as a definitive answer.